# Better Android File Transfer program

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, android

I need a way to hook up my android phone to my Mac and generate preview of the files when they reside on the device.

- The Android File Transfer program lacks view by icon. That is, I cannot see thumbnails of the photos on my phone that I want to drag and drop to the Desktop for example.
- Same with iTunes.

Is there a better program out there?

Answer (score 2):

AirDroid? It transfers data over WiFi instead USB: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid

Comment: +1, there are probably apps that are more focused on file transfer (AirDroid does a bunch of other stuff too), but it works pretty well for that in my experience.